# ArrayList return type in generic interface - <identifier> expected

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> {   
    public ArrayList<T> (int page, int count)  throws SQLException;
    public T Get(int key)  throws SQLException;
    public void Insert(T model) throws IllegalAccessException;
    public void Update(T model);
    public void Delete(int id);
}
```

This line `public ArrayList<T>` gives me a compiler error `error: <identifier> expected
    public ArrayList<T> (int page, int count)  throws SQLException;`

Could you help me make sense of it as in a class this actually seems to work?
For example if I get rid of that line in the interface, and have this class, it compiles ok:

```
public class MySqlRepository<T> implements IRepository<T> {
//[...]
//@Override -- no longer override
public ArrayList<T> GetAll(int page, int count) throws SQLException{
    //"SELECT * FROM {table} LIMIT " + count + " OFFSET " + offset + ";"
    int offset = page * count;
    StringBuilder sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    sqlBuilder.append("Select FROM ")
        .append(modelClass.getName().toLowerCase())
        .append("s ")
        .append("LIMIT ")
        .append(count)
        .append(" OFFSET ")
        .append(offset)
        .append(";");

    ResultSet set = sqlConnection.createStatement().executeQuery(sqlBuilder.toString());

    ArrayList<T> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

    while(set.next())
    {
        resultList.add(createFromCurrentLine(set));
    }
    return resultList;
}
//[...]
}
```

Why am I not able to use the generic in the ArrayList return type in the interface, when I can use it in the class?

Comment: If you are working with Java, you don't need to prefix your interface name with `I`. That is a convention followed in C#

Comment: You have specified a return type (ArrayList<T>) and a list of arguments (int page, int count), but no method **name**. Note that method names start with a lowercase letter in Java.

Comment: man I feel so stupid... I just missed that

Comment: the <identifier> is about the missing method name. but it is  confusing because you start looking at the generics because of <..>

Comment: If the answer(s) here helped you please accept one of them. This has a number of benefits for you, for the answerers and for other users of [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/). Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just specifying the return-type and the arguments that this method take. `public ArrayList<T> (int page, int count)  throws SQLException;`. But where are you specifying the name of the method?

As you are missing the **name** of the method, you are getting this compile-time error.

Just few more note points:

- You should return `java.util.List` instead of a specific type (`java.util.ArrayList`)
- You don't need to prefix your interface name with `I`. That is a convention followed in C#
- Method names in Java must preferably be starting with a lower-case character (and follow [camel-case notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)).

Comment: Perfect though it would be worth mentioning programming against more general interfaces: List.

Comment: And the missing name: GetAll.

Comment: I'll keep the notes in mind, but "must" is too strong a word since I am not actually forced to use camel case